# Numbering subsections and subsubsections with the equation counter

Tags: numbering

I would like to number everything within a section with the same counter: theorems, definitions, equations, subsections, etc. Everything that's numbered for reference (except for floats, since they are "out of sequence".) I am using the `amsbook` class.

I have made a beginning to this by putting most things on the equation counter like so:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\numberwithin{section}{chapter}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\newtheorem{thm}[equation]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{crl}[equation]{Corollary}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{dfn}[equation]{Definition}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Foo} % 1.1
\begin{thm} % 1.1.1
Some sets are finite.
\end{thm}
\begin{crl} % 1.1.2
Not all sets are infinite.
\end{crl}

\subsection{Bar} % 1.1.1
We find that
\begin{equation} % 1.1.3
2 = 1 + 1.
\end{equation}

\subsubsection{Baz} % 1.1.1.1
Furthermore,
\begin{equation} % 1.1.4
1 + 1 = 2.
\end{equation}

\section{Quux} % 1.2
Open questions remain.

\end{document}
```

In the example, I want subsection Bar to be numbered 1.1.3, its equation to be 1.1.4,
subsubsection Baz to be 1.1.5, and its equation to be 1.1.6. Then everything resets with the new section.

Comment: @Andrew How does that question address the issue of subsection numbering at issue here?

Comment: Probably mixing `\numberwithin` and `\newtheorem{}[]{}` will do the job.

Comment: @cfr Sorry, I missed the point of the question: I thought that the OP only wanted everything numbered within section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make `equation` an alias for the `subsection` counter and the same for `subsubsection`, but you also need to remove this counter from the reset list of `subsection`.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\counterwithout{subsubsection}{subsection}
\makeatletter
\let\c@equation\c@subsection
\let\theequation\thesubsection
\let\c@subsubsection\c@subsection
\let\thesubsubsection\thesubsection
\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}[subsection]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{crl}[subsection]{Corollary}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{dfn}[subsection]{Definition}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Foo} % 1.1
\begin{thm} % 1.1.1
Some sets are finite.
\end{thm}
\begin{crl} % 1.1.2
Not all sets are infinite.
\end{crl}

\subsection{Bar} % 1.1.1
We find that
\begin{equation} % 1.1.3
2 = 1 + 1.
\end{equation}

\subsubsection{Baz} % 1.1.1.1
Furthermore,
\begin{equation} % 1.1.4
1 + 1 = 2.
\end{equation}

\section{Quux} % 1.2
Open questions remain.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One way is to hijack the section command with something like:

```
\let\realsubsection\subsection% keep a copy
\def\subsection{\setcounter{subsection}{\arabic{equation}}% sync the counters
   \refstepcounter{equation}%
   \realsubsection% invoke the real \section
}
```

What this does is make the `subsection` counter equal to the current value of the `equation` counter whenever it is used (and also increments the `equation` counter).

I am confused by what you want `\subsubsection` to do, however, as your description sounds it it should be identical to `\subsection`. To me it makes more sense for it to create a subsubsection with the correct label, which is what my code does:

[image]

In actual fact, I didn't use the code above and instead recast everything to use the `subsection` counter. The reason for this is if you hack the `\subsection` command then you also need to hack the `\subsubsection` command to get it to work properly. Instead, I hacked `\equation`, which starts the `equation` environment. Here's the full mwe:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\numberwithin{section}{chapter}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\newtheorem{thm}[subsection]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{crl}[subsection]{Corollary}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{dfn}[subsection]{Definition}

\let\realequation\equation
\def\equation{\setcounter{equation}{\arabic{subsection}}%
   \refstepcounter{subsection}%
   \realequation}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Foo} % 1.1
\begin{thm} % 1.1.1
Some sets are finite.
\end{thm}
\begin{crl} % 1.1.2
Not all sets are infinite.
\end{crl}

\subsection{Bar} % 1.1.1
We find that
\begin{equation} % 1.1.3
2 = 1 + 1.
\end{equation}

\subsubsection{Baz} % 1.1.1.1
Furthermore,
\begin{equation} % 1.1.4
1 + 1 = 2.
\end{equation}

\section{Quux} % 1.2
Open questions remain.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Regarding subsubsections: I'd like them to be numbered in the same sequence as subsections, but retain their different styling, showing that they're subordinate. Also, if subsections are in some table of contents or something, subsubsections would still not be.